# Scrapy: How to populate empty items with ItemLoader?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am new to Scrapy and need a bit of help as I looked through different threads and it is difficult for me to find a solution particularly for my case or I do not understand something.

I use **ItemLoader** to populate Items. Sometimes the pages I scrape are not consistent and there are missing xpaths that I define in the ***parse_item*** function. As a result, I get something like that (in JSON format):

```
[{
    "product_name": "Bonded top",
    "sizes": ["S", "L", "XL"],
    "product_url": "http://www.website.com/product/bonded-top"
}, {
    "product_name": "Red glasses",
    "product_url": "http://www.website.com/product/red-glasses"
}]
```

While I am working with JSON, this is not a big issue, however, if I would export items into .csv, the data, as you can imagine, will be mixed. This is a small example, I have many more items and thousands of products. Some of the items might be missing ("sizes" is missing in the example above).

**Question**

What would be an elegant way for populating empty strings as key values e.g. {"sizes":""}? I do not completely understand, where should I configure, that even empty strings can be populated, given that I use ItemLoader?

My configuration looks like this:

**Items**

```
class MytheresaItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_url = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())    
    product_name = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    sizes = scrapy.Field()
```

**Spider**

```
class MytheresaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'website_products'
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.website.com/en/clothing.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),
                       restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="category-products"]/ul')),
         callback='parse_item',
         ),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),
                       restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pages"]/ul/li[@class="next"]')),
         follow=True,
         ),
    )


def parse_item(self, response):
    i = ItemLoader(item=MytheresaItem(), response=response)

    i.add_value('product_url', response.url)

    i.add_xpath('sizes', '//div[@class="product-essential"] \
        /descendant::div[@class="product-options"] \
        /descendant::ul[@class="sizes"]/child::*/a/span/text()')

    i.add_xpath('product_name','//div[@class="product-essential"] \
        /descendant::div[@class="product-name"]/span/text()')

    return i.load_item()
```

Comment: I just came across this snippet from the documentation and it looks like the kind of thing you need. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.BaseItemExporter.export_empty_fields, I don't have time to explore it further, hth. "Whether to include empty/unpopulated item fields in the exported data. Defaults to False. Some exporters (like CsvItemExporter) ignore this attribute and always export all empty fields."

Comment: Sadly I also found this "The export_empty_fields attribute has no effect on this exporter." reffereing to the CSV exporter.

Comment: Steve, thanks. I will look into that more. So far, I have been using terminal command 'scrapy crawl spider_name -o products.csv -t csv'

Comment: What do you do with the CSV file once you've filled it with scraped data? It also just occured to me that the csv file format will have a field for every column in every row even if there's no actual data. For example, a line might read "value1, value2,, value4". There is no value3 but the commas surrounding it are still issued to prevent value4 being misinterpreted.

Comment: Yes, this is true... Although, how should I go about product description, which usually may contain commas or semicolons?

Comment: That type of text needs to be surrounded by quotes, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864243/scrapy-issues-with-csv-exporting, and the code `self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(open(spider.name+".csv", "w"), False, 
                                        fields_to_export=self.fields_to_export, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`

Comment: alright, thanks for that tip, I definitely need to look into this solution. The only question - where should I define self.exporter, in which file?